# How to use glTexStorage2DMultisample() about OpenGL ES ？

Tags: opengl-es

I want implement off-screen Anti-aliasing.

First init Texture and FBO :

```
int[] textures = new int[1];
GLES31.glGenTextures(1,textures,0);
textureFBO.handle = textures[0];
GLES31.glActiveTexture(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES31.glBindTexture(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE,textures[0]);
GLES31.glTexStorage2DMultisample(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE,4, GLES31.GL_RGBA8, frameWidth, frameHeight, false);
             ... 
int[] frameBuffers = new int[1];
GLES31.glGenFramebuffers(1, frameBuffers,0);
GLES31.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES31.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES31.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, textureFBO.handle, 0);
GLES31.glBindTexture(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 0);
```

Then render to FBO :

```
GLES31.glBindFramebuffer(GLES31.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffers[0]);
        ...
GLES31.glActiveTexture(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES31.glBindTexture(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTextureOriginal.handle);
GLES31.glDrawArrays(GLES31.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Finally, sampling multiTexture, render it to FBO0

```
GLES31.glBindFramebuffer(GLES31.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        ...
GLES31.glActiveTexture(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES31.glBindTexture(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, textureFBO.handle);
GLES31.glDrawArrays(GLES31.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

But the render result is black.

If i replace glTexStorage2DMultisample() using glTexStorage2D(), it works fine.

Comment: "*so i need to add more words, but i don't think there are more i need to add, so this sentence just to satisfy the rule*" We have that rule for a reason. Because putting a title on something and throwing down a line of code says nothing about what your problem is and makes it impossible for us to help solve it. Instead of fighting against a rule you don't like, make use that as a chance to help people help you by explaining what the problem is.

Comment: the format rule's drive me crazy... i  add my code using  ```\n code  \n```, and the preview looks very good. but it keep hinting  【Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.】 and i using CTRL+K , it still not work... why is it so hard compare with github?

Comment: so i  CTRL+K the all content, it become like this,  and it hint too much code, need more details, so i add the word below, now it become like this @NicolBolas

Comment: "*why is it so hard compare with github*" It *does* work like GitHub markdown. If you had used backticks without the indentation. I don't know why the error message still suggests using indentation though.

Comment: Also, while your question is now comprehensible, I still don't know what you're trying to do. I mean, I see that you're wanting to switch to a multisampled render target and texture. But my question is what you intend for this to actually *do*? Like, when your shader samples from a texture, what do you expect to get?

Comment: Yes, i still can't find what is wrong, i use github mostly,  never encounter this problem.

Comment: I want to add Antialiasing. @NicolBolas

Answer (score 1):

You can not access multisample texture like usual ones in shader, as per the spec (check section 8.8 MULTISAMPLE TEXTURES):

> When a multisample texture is accessed in a shader, the access takes one vector
> of integers describing which texel to fetch and an integer corresponding to the
> sample numbers described in section 13.2.1 describing which sample within the
> texel to fetch. No standard sampling instructions are allowed on the multisample
> texture targets, and no filtering is performed by the fetch.

The usual way of using a multisample texture is first downscale it to a texture use `glBlitFramebuffer`, check the section about AA in [Learn OpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Anti-Aliasing) for more details (The tutorial is about OpenGL, changing `glTexImage2DMultisample` to `glTexStorage2DMultisample` and it is applicable to OpenGL ES 3.1)